Getting "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier '$'" after upgrading from angular 14 to 16 in google docs addon
My Google docs addon which is based on Angular was working perfect with angular 14 but when I upgraded it from v14 to v17 I start getting these errors where ever there is '$' symbol used in my code.

I am getting this error only when app is running inside the google docs addon container. It is working fine outside of it.
I tried removing es3plugin from webpack config but it didn't work. here is my webpack config file:
const path = require('path');
const GasPlugin = require('gas-webpack-plugin');
const ES3Plugin = require('webpack-es3-plugin');

module.exports = {
    mode: 'development',
    devtool: 'inline-source-map',
    entry: {
        'Code.js': './src/google-apps-script/server.ts',
        'Code.ext.js': './src/google-apps-script/api.ts',
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.ts$/,
                use: 'ts-loader',
                exclude: /node_modules/,
            },
        ],
    },
    resolve: {
        extensions: ['.tsx', '.ts', '.js'],
    },
    output: {
        filename: 'my-addon-gdocs/[name]',
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
    },
    plugins: [new GasPlugin(), new ES3Plugin()],
};


